# Eclipse Kepler crashes when creating new Android Application Project

Tags: android, eclipse, crash, eclipse-kepler

As the title reads, it crashes every time I make a new android app project. It seems to run fine when I make a new Java project, however. The error code i get is: Java was started but returned with exit code: -805306369.

That's all I could post, i can't seem to copy the error message (it's a pop-up, doesn't appear on console)

Just as it's about to load the project, eclipse goes Not Responding for a long time, so I'm forced to close it and I get that error message.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Perhaps not the help you want, but IntelliJ/Android Studio work much better than Eclipse.  Save yourself...

Comment: Do you know which one it's trying to start?

Comment: @AndrewKor: Does Keppler comes bundled with Java 7 (1.7)? If so, Android won't work as it currently only support upto Java 6 (1.6).

Comment: @ChuongPham: I have Java 7 installed (installed it before kepler). I'll download Java 6 thank you!

Comment: @AndrewKor: Let me know if you still have problem with Eclipse. Remember to change your JDK to point to Java 6 installed directory under Preferences in Eclipse. Otherwise, Eclipse will still run with Java 7.

Comment: @ChuongPham: Thanks Chuong. It no longer crashes anymore after doing what you did. I'm getting a new error, however, that I didn't get before: An error has occurred. org/eclipse/ui/part/MultiPageEditorPart. Every time I click on a view or try to open up a project, I get that popup. Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: Andrew: That's a Eclipse-Keppler-specific error relating to the codes editor. Judging by the long list of bugs filed by developers for Keppler, I would stay away from it for the time being. Indigo is stable, you might want to try this release instead of Keppler.

Comment: @ChuongPham: When I open Indigo, the loading screen is Kepler, oddly enough. When eclipse is open, and I view "About Eclipse", it says the version is Indigo and I still get that error

Comment: Edit: Re-extracted the files, and Indigo seems to be working well now with no errors. Still getting the Kepler loading screen, however.

Comment: @AndrewKor: I've just tested Eclipse Juno (a bit more current than Indigo) by creating a new Android project and it work without any issue. Can you please try Juno? Also, see my answer below. I know it's a pain to follow but it would save you a lot of wasted time in the future.

Comment: @blahdiblah According to [the offical Android developer site](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) Android Studio is still at preview status. My experience with it a couple of months ago persuaded me to stick with Eclipse until Android Studio is properly released.

Comment: After dealing with lot of instabilities of ADT Eclipse plugin I switched to ADT bundle with Eclipse already included. Unfortunately the bundled Eclipse isn't any latest version and has limited capabilities to develop for other platforms than Android. So I ended keeping two Eclipses one for Java development and another for Android.

Comment: Change Application GTK Theme to Adwaita as explained [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25016604/eclipse-crashes-when-creating-a-new-android-project/26368966#26368966

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Eclipse to build Android, do the following in order:

1. Install the **JDK** from Oracle. You can get the JDK [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
2. Install **Eclipse** (e.g. Eclipse Standard version). As of November 2013, **Juno** (Eclipse v4.2.2) is the most stable release of Eclipse. Refrain from using Kepler release for now. You can get old, stable release of Eclipse [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Older_Versions_Of_Eclipse). Or, new version [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) if it is stable. ***Important**: When you install Eclipse, do not overwrite an existing Eclipse installed directory but instead create a new directory and install Eclipse there. This would prevent getting libraries mixed up between different versions of Eclipse.*
3. Install the **Android SDK**. You can get the SDK [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). For beginners, choose the **installer_r22.3-windows.exe** package.
4. Install the **Android Development Tools (ADT)**. You can get the ADT [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html).
5. Start Eclipse.
6. From Eclipse's menu, select **Window | Preferences**. Then, select **Java | Installed JREs** option. Check to see if Eclipse has listed correctly the JDK installed directory created from step 1 above. If not, click **Add** button and browse to your JDK installed directory. On Windows, this directory is normally found under `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45` (e.g. Java 1.6 release 45).
7. In Eclipse's **Preferences** screen, select **Android** option and check that the directory of the Android **SDK Location** is correct. It should be correct if you have successfully completed step 3 above.
8. To create a new Android project, from Eclipse's menu select **File | New | Android Application Project**. Fill in the required information in the **New Android Application** screen and click **Finish** when done.

**OPTIONAL**: Under Eclipse's **Window** menu option, there are two Android submenu options: Android SDK Manager and Android Virtual Device Manager.

a. The **Android SDK Manager** option allows you to install/remove versions and/or components used for Android development.

b. The **Android Virtual Device Manager** option allows you to create virtual Android devices for development and testing purposes. For example, an Android virtual device with a `Target` of **Android 2.1 - API Level 7** will allow you to test your Android application that will later run in production on devices - phones, tablets, notes - that run Android firmware version 2.1.