# Error when launching eclipse adt

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I've been googling it and couldn't find anything or anyone explaining how to tackle the issue.
Basically whenever I run eclipse it will run but this error will appear:

```
Error: Error parsing the AVDs
Unable to get the Android SDK home directory.
Make sure the environment variable ANDROID_SDK_HOME is set up.
```

What do I do to fix it? Sorry I'm new to eclipse. I used to develop websites on php and javascript. SO I need help of more experienced folks please...

Comment: Are you sure you did everything correct on installing android sdk?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Windows, have a look at this SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19803611/eclipse-kepler-crashes-when-creating-new-android-application-project/19876732#19876732).

If you use Linux, you'll need to set your environment properly to point to Android SDK's home, JDK's home, etc.