# Eclipse crashes when creating a new android project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ubuntu, sdk

I'm starting with Android Programming at the moment. I'm using die Android SDK and Eclipse. I downloaded the Bundle from the [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) . At first it seems good, but when finishing the wizard for a new Android Project, Eclipse crashes.
[image: Snapshot]
The programm returns the following error:

[image: Snapshot of console]
I already tried to run "ulimit -c unlimited", with no effect.

I'm running Kubuntu 14.04 (Linux/Debian/Ubuntu) and Java 1.7.0_55.

Any help?

Comment: maybe this link will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383992/why-does-my-eclipse-indigo-crash-on-ubuntu-13-04-with-oracle-jdk-64bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the Desktop Theme to a different theme.

For KDE users goto: *Configure Desktop* => *Application Appearance* => *GTK* and change the theme from *oxygen-gtk* to *Adwaita*. Your Eclipse will no longer crash and the desktop will look more premium.

[image]

Comment: OK, thank you very much... I gonna try this later
Why is my desktop theme affecting my Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

Have you try reinstall OpenJDK?

```
sudo apt-get install -reinstall openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jdk
```

Comment: Yes, i have.
No effect, too.

Answer (score 1):

try paste this line in eclipse.ini file in your Eclipse catalog:

-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla

Example:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
adtproduct
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```